# xml soap with swift (IOS 8)

Tags: ios, xml, web-services, soap, swift

I have an Asp.net web service (SOAP) and there are some methods (functions)
I want to call one of the methods that I have it on my web service the pares the result (XML result)

Exactly what I need to now:

1- how to call my webservice (SOAP)
2- the return result like this

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><FirstName>test</FirstName><MI>A</MI> <LastName>testLast</LastName>
```

how can I pares it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a pod for mapping XML to objects, called [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper). (uses the same technique as the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper))

Using the [Requests](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper#requests-subspec) subspec you can create a `SOAPEnvelope` like:

```
let soapMessage = SOAPMessage(soapAction: "ActionName", nameSpace: "ActionNameSpace")
let soapEnvelope = SOAPEnvelope(soapMessage: soapMessage)
```

And then send it with Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: soapEnvelope.toXML(), encoding: XMLEncoding.soap(withAction: "ActionNameSpace#ActionName"))
```

Mapping the response XML requires you to implement `XMLMappable` protocol

For example you can map the following xml:

```
<Food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <description>
        Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
    </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</Food>
```

With `Food` object:

```
class Food: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var name: String!
    var price: Float!
    var description: String?
    var calories: Int?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        name <- map["name"]
        price <- map["price"]
        description <- map["description"]
        calories <- map["calories"]
    }
}
```

Using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and `responseXMLObject(completionHandler:)` function like:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseXMLObject { (response: DataResponse<Food>) in
    let food = response.result.value
    print(food.toXMLString() ?? "nil")
}
```

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I made this new simple and lightweight XML parser for iOS in Swift - [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML)

You can use it to read XML data like this:

```
let someValue = xmlDocument["element"]["child"]["anotherChild"].value
```

or you can use it to build XML string like this:

```
let document = AEXMLDocument()
let element = document.addChild("element")
element.addChild("child")
document.xmlString // returns XML string of the entire document structure
```

I hope that helps.